# how do i control the fan speed in macbook pro 13" using ubuntu 12.04

Tags: fan

how do I control the fan speed on a macbook pro?

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I want the fan run faster because the laptop getting very hot

the laptop was released in October 2008 the model number is A1278

can someone please help me

Comment: What year was your model released? (We need the specific Laptop model like, 7.3 etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Install macfanctld, fan control daemon for Apple MacBook.

```
sudo apt-get install macfanctld
```

That should solve your problem on Ubuntu 12.04 and higher.